# Using thunks in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm wondering how to use async action creators in `mapDispatchToProps` for `react-redux`'s `connect`. I'm using the `redux-thunk` middleware and the following is my `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        foo: function() {
            dispatch(someAction());

            return function asyncAction(dispatch, getState) {
                console.log("An async action!");
                dispatch(someOtherAction(getState().foo));
            };
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I do the above, the async action does not get executed. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest declaring your actual thunk (`someOtherAction`) differently. In the following example, `asyncAction` is an async action creator which returns a thunk. The thunk can then dispatch other actions (after a promise resolves for example).

```
function asyncActionCreator () {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(someAction());

    someAsyncStuff().then(() => {
      dispatch(someOtherAction(getState().foo);
    });
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    foo: () => dispatch(asyncActionCreator())
  }
}
```

Comment: Along with that: the `bindActionCreators` utility can be used to replace that anonymous function, and the `mapDispatch` argument itself offers an object literal shorthand for binding:  `connect(mapState, {foo : asyncActionCreator})(MyComponent)`.

Comment: How could this work ?? It should be  `foo: () => asyncActionCreator()(dispatch)`

Comment: @SadokMtir, it should not. You dispatch actions created by an action creator, in this case `asyncActionCreator`. This example makes use of `redux-thunk` which changes the signature of your action creators (or rather adds thunks as an option vs a plain object). This thunk's signature has `dispatch` as its first parameter.

Comment: This example did not work on my example where the action creator returns a promise. `export const sendInquiry = postalCode =>
  dispatch => new Promise((resolve) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ActionTypes.SEND_INQUIRY,
      postalCode,
    });
    resolve();
  });
`

This way was solved: `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: {
    sendInquiry: x => sendInquiry(x)(dispatch),
  },
});
`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I'm going to add this.
I needed to dispatch 2 actions using 1 action creator but the second action was depending on the result of the first. The second action also needed access to a different slice of the store so I couldn't use the same reducer I was using to set the first value.

My mapDispatchToProps, using redux-thunk, ended up looking as follow:

```
import constants from '../constants';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setValuesToStore: (value) => {
            const firstAction = {
                type: constants.SET_FIRST_VALUE,
                value,
            }
            dispatch(firstAction)
            dispatch(secondAction())
            function secondAction() {
                return (dispatch, getState) => {
                    const state = getState()
                    dispatch({
                        type: constants.SET_SECOND_VALUE,
                        state,
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way I didn't need to import the store as a module, which I found very ugly. No biggie, just hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is clearly preferable, I believe this small modification to your code might also help to understand how this mechanism works:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        foo: () => dispatch(function() { // <-- Note the dispatch!
            dispatch(someAction());

            return function asyncAction(dispatch, getState) {
                console.log("An async action!");
                dispatch(someOtherAction(getState().foo));
            };
        }()) // <-- Note the IIFE!
    }
}
```

Your original thunk-creating function (associated with `foo`) here must actually be [immediately invoked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and `dispatch`'ed, for this pattern to work.