# Aplication works but generates an error: mapDispatchToProps() in Connect(App) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have written small app with Redux/Thunk. It works but it also generates an error msg as in title.  By work and not work here I mean receiving content from external file and make it available to app

I have tried to rewrite critical fragment to syntax probably more correct, but then it stopped working. By work and not work here I mean receiving content from external file and make it available to application. The very general idea is that when App.js (React/Hooks) is mounted it dispatches Thunk action of getting data from external source.

Here is shortened version of index.js

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {reducer} from './reducer';

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk) );


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><ConnectedApp /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here below part of actions.js

```
export function getData() {

  return dispatch => {

    // set state to "loading"
    dispatch(getDataRequested());

    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/8qjek")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // set state for success
        const dane = data.map(Object.values);
        dispatch(getDataDone(dane));

      })
      .catch(error => {
        // set state for error
        dispatch(getDataFailed(error));
      })
  }
}
```

and of App.js

```
  useEffect(() => getData(), []);
  const {state} ={...props}



const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {state};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = getData;

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

export default ConnectedApp;
```

I have checked two other versions of mapDispatchToProps, but while probably syntactically correct, I do not receive content.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getData: () => getData()
  }
};
```

and

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {getData: getData()}
```

Could someone help me? That is shortened version, I can of course add any code necessary.

Comment: You should probably not use fetch within the action itself. Action should be pure and should do the same thing with the same output and not really on fetch for example. To have a side-effect like fetch, you should use middleware or react-thunk

Comment: Honestly this looks like a bad pattern, and the code is a bit unreadable, first of all you should use something like redux-thunk or middleware, and put all your actions in a separate file.
Then import the actions and inject them in the connect HOC
`const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, myActions)(App);`
And access your state:
`const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {myPieceOfState: state.myPieceOfState};
};`

Comment: @Madeo I do both - actions are separate, and middleware is applied

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `bindActionCreators` from the `redux` library.

Like so:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
```

Where `ActionCreators` could be your `getData`.

Comment: `getData` needs access to the `dispatch` function to `dispatch` multiple actions. `bindActionCreators` doesn't make sense in this context as `getData` is not a simple action creator that returns an action object.

Answer (score 0):

Try `adding dispatch` call before calling action creator `getData()`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getData: () => dispatch(getData())
  }
};
```

Comment: `getData` doesn't return an action - it dispatches multiple actions and needs access to the `dispatch`er.

Comment: He is using `redux thunk` as middleware and has access to dispatch from store. So you don't need to send dispatch in parameter but surely need to bind the call in dispatch in mapDispatchToProps. For [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003574/using-thunks-in-mapdispatchtoprops/52233976)

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I missed the thunk middleware.

Comment: I tried but it says I can't change it unless you edit your post. Can you make a small edit and then I can reverse it?

Comment: Glad to know that